I was making my My code responsive using tailwind and it isn't starting no more
Error: Got unexpected undefined
    at nullthrows (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
    at RequestGraph.invalidateOptionNodes (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:248:44)
    at loadRequestGraph (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:872:18)
    at async RequestTracker.init (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:822:17)
    at async Parcel._init (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:188:28)
    at async Parcel.watch (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\Parcel.js:260:7)
    at async run (E:\PranishBista Intellij Assignment Tailwind\node_modules\parcel\lib\cli.js:283:9) {
  framesToPop: 1

I was trying to make my code responsive using tailwind css and it was working absolutely fine and then i got this error.No idea what to do tried a lot to fix it but nothing seems to work.
I dont know what code would help you find the error , let me know if anything i can provide would help. I tried npm start , build re installing tailwind
